# How would one create wrappers for property attributes?

Tags: c#, attributes, wrapper

In ASP.NET MVC we can use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace to assist with form/ model input validation.

If I didn't want to be tied to any specific framework i.e. xVal, EntLib Val Block, etc. and I wanted to create basically a wrapper classes to protect my code from the direct dependency how would one accomplish that?

So instead of my model property looking like this;

```
[Required]
property string Name {get;set;}
```

I want it to be tied to my code where the validation framework preferred will be implemented.

```
[MyRequired]
property string Name {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to derive your attribute from the underlying ones. EG:

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : EntLib.RequiredAttribute { }
```

That way you could modify the `MyRequiredAttribute` class later to derive from a different base class, and the rest of your code wouldn't need to change (you would probably however need to recompile it). The EntLib (etc) code that scans for `EntLib.RequiredAttribute` should still pick your derived attribute up

This relies on the underlying attribute not being sealed though.